# Angular Form Post

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following code and when I submit the request; I get request failed. The data is not going to the server. Any idea why?

All I need is a simple form submission with the code below. I think the issue is where I'm collecting the form data using the config section. I looked around and that's how I added that. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header" ng-controller="NotesCtrl">

            <h1>{{title}}</h1>

            <form class="row-height" name="Form1" ng-submit="processForm('ajaxSubmitResult')">
                <!--ng-submit="processForm(formData, 'ajaxSubmitResult') -->
                First Name:
                <input type="text" ng-model="formData.firstname" class="spacer" required/>
                Last Name:
                <input type="text" ng-model="formData.lastname" class="spacer" required/>
                <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="insert(formData)">Add</button>-->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Name</button>
            </form>

            <hr/>
            <h4>Raw Data</h4>
            {{formData}}

            <hr/>
            <h4>Submit Results</h4>
            <span id="submitDebugText">{{ajaxSubmitResult | json}}</span>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        // define angular module/app
        var formApp = angular.module('formApp', []);

        function NotesCtrl($scope, $http) {
            $scope.title = "Test App";
            $scope.formData = {};


            $scope.processForm = function (resultVarName) {
                var config = {
                    params: {
                        'firstname': $scope.firstname,
                        'lastname': $scope.lastname
                    }
                };

                $http.post("//", null, config)
                        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            $scope[resultVarName] = data;
                        })
                        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            $scope[resultVarName] = "bugger! Errors.";
                        });
            };

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: `$http.post("//"` - any reason you have two slashes there?

Comment: I'm just testing. I just want to see the data before it goes to POST. Is there a way to debug and see what's going on..

Comment: have you tried `console.log`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do something like this in the view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="formData.firstname" class="spacer" required/>
```

In the controller, you access the property with

```
$scope.formData.firstName
```

This issue seems to be that you aren't including the `formData` here:

```
 var config = {
                params: {
                    'firstname': $scope.firstname,
                    'lastname': $scope.lastname
                }
            };
```

Change that to

```
 var config = {
                params: {
                    'firstname': $scope.formData.firstname,
                    'lastname': $scope.formData.lastname
                }
            };
```

And you should be good to go.